# Hyperbolic sine of a logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

> Re-express $11\sinh(\ln 8)$ in the form $n/m$ where n and m are integers.

I am not sure where to start. Never went over something like this, its probably very easy though.

Comment: Logarithms have to do with exponential function. So does $\sinh$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{sh} (x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^x - e^{-x})$
$$11\mathrm{sh} (\ln 8) = 11\cdot\frac{1}{2}(e^{\ln 8}-e^{-\ln 8})$$